# FLOT: How do I show the figures for "spread" in the bars?

Tags: javascript, graph, flot

My code works well, so it's not that I need help with. But I have been trying to get this done for a while and I can't find many other pages to help with this so I was hoping someone would be able to help me.

My graph consists of 2 lines - to display the data and a bars to show how much "spread" is between the two. I have entered dummy data which is why the numbers won't add up properly.

How would I be able to insert the numbers into the bars for the "spread" array so they display permanently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [value labels plugin](https://github.com/winne27/flot-valuelabels)

```
    valueLabels: {
      show: true,
      xoffset: 50 // depends on your chart width and number of bars
    },
```

```js
! function(a) {
  "use strict";

  function e(e) {
    e.hooks.draw.push(function(e, t) {
      var l, s, o, i, r, n, d, f, u, b, h, v, x, g, c, L, w, p, m, M, y, z, O, C = {},
        B = "left";
      a.each(e.getData(), function(a, P) {
        if (P.valueLabels.show) {
          var k = P.valueLabels.showLastValue,
            A = P.valueLabels.showMaxValue,
            S = P.valueLabels.showMinValue,
            F = P.valueLabels.showTextLabel,
            V = P.valueLabels.labelFormatter,
            Z = P.valueLabels.xoffset,
            T = P.valueLabels.yoffset,
            D = P.valueLabels.xoffsetMin || Z,
            I = P.valueLabels.yoffsetMin || T,
            R = P.valueLabels.xoffsetMax || Z,
            X = P.valueLabels.yoffsetMax || T,
            Y = P.valueLabels.xoffsetLast || Z,
            j = P.valueLabels.yoffsetLast || T,
            Q = P.valueLabels.valign,
            W = P.valueLabels.valignLast || Q,
            q = P.valueLabels.valignMin,
            E = P.valueLabels.valignMax,
            G = P.valueLabels.align,
            H = P.valueLabels.horizAlign,
            J = P.valueLabels.horizAlignMin || H,
            K = P.valueLabels.horizAlignMax || H,
            N = P.valueLabels.horizAlignLast || H,
            U = P.valueLabels.fontcolor || "#222222",
            $ = P.valueLabels.shadowColor,
            _ = P.valueLabels.font || P.xaxis.font || "9pt san-serif",
            aa = P.valueLabels.hideZero,
            ea = P.valueLabels.hideSame,
            ta = P.valueLabels.reverseAlignBelowZero,
            la = P.valueLabels.showShadow,
            sa = P.valueLabels.useDecimalComma,
            oa = P.stack,
            ia = P.valueLabels.decimals,
            ra = P.valueLabels.useBackground,
            na = P.valueLabels.backgroundColor,
            da = P.valueLabels.useBorder,
            fa = P.valueLabels.borderColor;
          P.seriesIndex = a;
          var ua = null,
            ba = -1e3,
            ha = -1e3,
            va = "categories" == P.xaxis.options.mode,
            xa = "categories" == P.yaxis.options.mode;
          if (O = P.points.show ? P.points.radius - P.points.lineWidth / 2 : 0, (S || A) && "undefined" != typeof P.data[0]) {
            P.data[0][0] = +P.data[0][0], P.data[0][1] = +P.data[0][1];
            for (var ga = +P.data[0][0], ca = +P.data[0][0], La = +P.data[0][1], wa = +P.data[0][1], pa = 1; pa < P.data.length; ++pa) P.data[pa][0] = +P.data[pa][0], P.data[pa][1] = +P.data[pa][1], +P.data[pa][0] < ga && (ga = +P.data[pa][0]), +P.data[pa][0] > ca && (ca = +P.data[pa][0]), +P.data[pa][1] < La && (La = +P.data[pa][1]), +P.data[pa][1] > wa && (wa = +P.data[pa][1])
          } else {
            S = !1, A = !1;
            for (var pa = 0; pa < P.data.length; ++pa) P.data[pa][0] = +P.data[pa][0], P.data[pa][1] = +P.data[pa][1]
          }
          g = S || A || k;
          for (var pa = 0; pa < P.data.length; ++pa)
            if (null !== P.data[pa]) {
              if (s = P.data[pa][0], d = P.data[pa][1], l = F && P.data[pa].length > 2 ? P.data[pa][2] : !1, g) {
                if (c = !1, S && La == d && !P.bars.horizontal ? (c = !0, n = D, h = I, v = q, S = !1) : S && ga == s && P.bars.horizontal ? (c = !0, n = D, h = I, x = J, S = !1) : A && wa == d && !P.bars.horizontal ? (c = !0, n = R, h = X, v = E, A = !1) : A && ca == s && P.bars.horizontal ? (c = !0, n = R, h = X, x = K, A = !1) : k && pa == P.data.length - 1 && !P.bars.horizontal ? (c = !0, n = Y, h = j, v = W) : k && pa == P.data.length - 1 && P.bars.horizontal && (c = !0, n = Y, h = j, x = N), !c) continue
              } else ta && 0 > d && !P.bars.horizontal ? (n = Z, h = -1 * T, "above" == Q ? Q = "below" : "below" == Q && (Q = "above"), v = Q) : (n = Z, h = T, v = Q, x = H);
              if ("top" == v && (v = "above"), va && (s = P.xaxis.categories[s]), xa && (d = P.yaxis.categories[d]), !(s < P.xaxis.min || s > P.xaxis.max || d < P.yaxis.min || d > P.yaxis.max)) {
                if (l !== !1) L = l;
                else {
                  if (L = P.bars.horizontal ? s : d, null == L && (L = ""), 0 === L && (aa || oa)) continue;
                  ia !== !1 && (L = parseFloat(L).toFixed(ia))
                }
                P.valueLabels.valueLabelFunc && (L = P.valueLabels.valueLabelFunc({
                  series: P,
                  seriesIndex: a,
                  index: pa
                })), L = "" + L, L = V(L), ea && L == ua && pa != P.data.length - 1 || (P.bars.horizontal && (t.font = _, y = da || ra ? 10 : 6, Math.abs(P.xaxis.p2c(s) - P.xaxis.p2c(0)) < t.measureText(L).width + Math.abs(n) + y && "outside" != x && (n = -1 * n, x = "outside")), sa && (L = L.toString().replace(".", ",")), w = 0, oa && (C[s] || (C[s] = 0), w = C[s], C[s] = C[s] + d), o = P.xaxis.p2c(s) + e.getPlotOffset().left, f = P.yaxis.p2c(d + w) + e.getPlotOffset().top, (!ea || Math.abs(f - ha) > 20 || o > ba) && (ua = L, ba = o + 8 * L.length, ha = f, P.bars.horizontal ? (b = f, z = "middle", s >= 0 ? "outside" == x ? (B = "left", n += 4) : "insideMax" == x ? (B = "right", n -= 4) : "insideCenter" == x ? (B = "center", o = e.getPlotOffset().left + P.xaxis.p2c(0) + (P.xaxis.p2c(s) - P.xaxis.p2c(0)) / 2 + n) : "insideZero" == x && (B = "left", o = e.getPlotOffset().left + P.xaxis.p2c(0) + 3 + n) : "outside" == x ? (B = "right", n -= 4) : "insideMax" == x ? (B = "left", n += 4) : "insideCenter" == x ? (B = "center", o = e.getPlotOffset().left + P.xaxis.p2c(0) + (P.xaxis.p2c(s) - P.xaxis.p2c(0)) / 2 + n) : "insideZero" == x && (B = "right", o = e.getPlotOffset().left + P.xaxis.p2c(0) - 4 + n), r = o + n) : ("bottom" == v ? (z = "bottom", f = e.getPlotOffset().top + e.height()) : "middle" == v ? (z = "middle", M = e.getPlotOffset().top + e.height(), f = (M + f) / 2) : "below" == v ? (z = "top", h = h + 4 + O) : "above" == v && (z = "bottom", h = h - 2 - O), r = o + n, b = f + h, 0 >= f && (b += 16), o >= e.width() + e.getPlotOffset().left ? (r = e.width() + e.getPlotOffset().left + n - 3, B = "right") : B = G), t.font = _, (da || ra) && (m = t.measureText(L).width + 5, m % 2 == 1 && m++, p = parseInt(_, 10) + 7, "top" == z ? (u = b, b += 3) : "bottom" == z ? (u = b - p - 2, b -= 2) : "middle" == z && (u = b - (p + 1) / 2, b += 1), "right" == B ? (i = r - m + 1, r -= 2) : "left" == B ? (i = r, r += 3) : i = r - m / 2, t.shadowOffsetX = 0, t.shadowOffsetY = 0, t.shadowBlur = 0, da && (t.strokeStyle = fa, t.strokeRect(i, u, m, p)), ra && (t.fillStyle = na, t.fillRect(i, u, m, p))), t.fillStyle = U, la ? (t.shadowOffsetX = 0, t.shadowOffsetY = 0, t.shadowBlur = 1.5, t.shadowColor = $) : t.shadowBlur = 0, t.textAlign = B, t.textBaseline = z, t.fillText(L, r, b)))
              }
            }
        }
      })
    })
  }
  var t = {
    series: {
      valueLabels: {
        show: !1,
        showTextLabel: !1,
        showMaxValue: !1,
        showMinValue: !1,
        showLastValue: !1,
        labelFormatter: function(a) {
          return a
        },
        align: "center",
        valign: "above",
        valignMin: "below",
        valignMax: "above",
        horizAlign: "insideMax",
        xoffset: 0,
        yoffset: 0,
        useDecimalComma: !1,
        decimals: !1,
        hideZero: !1,
        hideSame: !1,
        reverseAlignBelowZero: !1,
        showShadow: !1,
        shadowColor: !1,
        useBackground: !1,
        backgroundColor: "#cccccc",
        fontcolor: "#222222",
        useBorder: !1,
        borderColor: "#999999"
      }
    }
  };
  a.plot.plugins.push({
    init: e,
    options: t,
    name: "valueLabels",
    version: "2.0.0"
  })
}(jQuery);

// end of plugin

$(function() {
  var dw = [
    [0, 2234506735], //Jan 16
    [1, 2423228540], //Feb 16
    [2, 2572325679], //Mar 16
    [3, 2623236552], //Apr 16
    [4, 2383236553], //May 16
    [5, 1116187626], //Jun 16
    [6, 6293855432], //Jul 16
    [7, 7415252345], //Aug 16
    [8, 7689084325], //Sep 16
    [9, 2548362329], //Oct 16
    [10, 284463540], //Nov 16
    [11, 3043645527], //Dec 16
    [12, 3232254269] //Jan 17
  ];

  var aa = [
    [0, 1923335489], //Jan 16
    [1, 214502542229], //Feb 16
    [2, 2286222221], //Mar 16
    [3, 23114561121], //Apr 16
    [4, 2099514524], //May 16
    [5, 24123654227], //Jun 16
    [6, 2049124532], //Jul 16
    [7, 20311414933], //Aug 16
    [8, 2242114241], //Sep 16
    [9, 23902434234], //Oct 16
    [10, 2412432216], //Nov 16
    [11, 260121224], //Dec 16
    [12, 2886112432] //Jan 17

  ];

  var spread = [
    [12, 271130622], //Jan 17
    [11, 437114103], //Dec 16
    [10, 400944311], //Nov 16
    [9, 40752051131], //Oct 16
    [8, 3483442413], //Sep 16
    [7, 2217514642], //Aug 16
    [6, 2441325340], //Jul 16
    [5, 3482373959], //Jun 16
    [4, 2846263212], //May 16
    [3, 33096755537], //Apr 16
    [2, 28438238666], //Mar 16
    [1, 2834506661], //Feb 16
    [0, 4798313216] //Jan 16
  ];

  /*Data indicating ticks/Xaxis values*/
  var ticks = [
    [0, "Jan 16"],
    [1, "Feb 16"],
    [2, "Mar 16"],
    [3, "Apr 16"],
    [4, "May 16"],
    [5, "Jun 16"],
    [6, "Jul 16"],
    [7, "Aug 16"],
    [8, "Sep 16"],
    [9, "Oct 16"],
    [10, "Nov 16"],
    [11, "Dec 16"],
    [12, "Jan 17"],
  ];

  var data = [{
    label: "Data Warehouse",
    data: dw,
    lines: {
      show: true
    },
    points: {
      show: true
    },
    color: "#009900"
  }, {
    label: "mation",
    data: aa,
    lines: {
      show: true
    },
    points: {
      show: true
    },
    color: "#0066ff" //orange
  }, {
    label: "Spread", //Plotting the Spread information
    data: spread,
    bars: {
      show: true
    },
    valueLabels: {
      show: true,
      xoffset: 50 // depends on your chart width and number of bars
    },
    color: " #862d86" //purple
  }];

  var options = { //Editing layout of graph
    xaxis: {
      ticks: ticks
    },
    grid: {
      hoverable: true,
      backgroundColor: {
        colors: ["#ffffff", "#ffffff"] //white
      }
    },
    legend: {
      labelBoxBorderColor: "#000000", //black
      container: $("#legendcontainer"),
      noColumns: 0
    }
  };

  function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
    $('<div id= "tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
      position: 'absolute',
      display: 'none',
      top: y + 5,
      left: x + 5,
      border: '1px solid #fdd',
      padding: '2px',
      'background-color': '#fee' //light pink
    }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
  };

  var previousPoint = null;
  $("#placeholder").bind("plothover", function(event, pos, item) {
    if (item) {
      if (previousPoint != item.dataIndex) {
        previousPoint = item.dataIndex;

        $("#tooltip").remove();
        var x = item.datapoint[0].toFixed(0),
          y = item.datapoint[1].toFixed(0);

        showTooltip(item.pageX, item.pageY, "(" + x + "," + y + ")");
      }
    } else {
      $("#tooltip").remove();
      previousPoint = null;
    }
  });

  var plot = $.plot($("#placeholder"),
    data, options);
});
```

```css
#title {
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.2/jquery.flot.min.js"></script>


<!--Declaring the graph and styling-->
<div id="paymentGraph">
  <div id="legendcontainer" style="width: 800px; margin-top: 170px;"></div>
  <div id="placeholder" style="width: 1450px;
     height:600px; 
     text-align: 
     center; 
     margin-top: 50px;
     margin-left: 150px"></div>
</div>

<!--Declaring the title and styling-->
<div id="title" style="position: absolute;
  left: 570px; 
  top: 5px; 
  color: black; 
  font-size: 45px">
  <b>Deposit Discrepancies<br> Adobe Analytics vs Data Warehouse</b>
</div>

<!--Declaring the Xaxis and styling-->
<div id="xaxis" style="position: absolute;
  left: 875px; 
  top: 875px; 
  color: black; 
  font-size: 16px">
  <em><b>Time</b></em>
</div>

<!--Declaring the Yaxis and styling-->
<div id="yaxis" style="position: absolute; 
  left: 50px; 
  top: 520px; 
  color: black; 
  font-size: 16px">
  <em><b>Number</br>of</br>Registrations</b></em>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when I try and implement it into my code. However, tt works when I run the code via this webpage?

Comment: Try to find the difference(s) between your code and the code snippet on this page.

Comment: This works now, thanks. One more question (I think), is it possible to make the numbers above the bars display in bold? and potentially to show them in the format of 1,922,689 instead of 1922689?

Comment: See the `labelFormatter` option in he [wiki](https://github.com/winne27/flot-valuelabels/wiki).

Comment: I have now managed to do this, thanks!! How would I display the figures in these arrays as percentages?

Comment: I think that should be a new question.

Comment: Okay, made it as a new question. If you'd be able to help me out, i would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42437730/how-would-i-display-the-figures-in-these-arrays-as-percentages